# How to make folder urls offline with HTML5?

Tags: html, offline, offline-caching, cache-manifest

My web application uses folder urls only (with mvc routes). I am wondering how I can cache some of these urls, and prticularly the site root.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
/
.
/myfolder
/myfolder/
myfolder
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it really exotic to do that?
Should I do differently?

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work.  Have you tested it?  It validates fine in http://manifest-validator.com/ (I wasn't sure about the "." -- I think it's redundant though).

I think simply /myfolder will work.

To test, simply open the app from chrome with the javascript console up.  You'll see the various caching operations.

Greg